# How To Convert Raw SQL to SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLAlchemy models set up in python:

```
class Relation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'relations'

    relation_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True)
    article_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("articles.id"),
        nullable=False)
    entity_id1 = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("entities.entity_id"),
        nullable=False)
    entity_id2 = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("entities.entity_id"),
        nullable=False)
    confidence = db.Column(
        db.Integer
        )


class Entity(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'entities'
    entity_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
```

And I am trying to convert the following SQL query string into an SQLAlchemy query (POSTGRES if it matters) and the main goal is to prevent SQL injection:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT e.name, e.entity_id FROM entities e RIGHT JOIN 
   relations r ON e.entity_id=r.entity_id1 OR e.entity_id=r.entity_id2 
   WHERE (r.entity_id1 = PARAMETER OR r.entity_id2 = PARAMETER) 
   AND e.entity_id<>PARAMETER;
```

Here is my attempt, but the error message I am receiving suggests there is an issue with the join:

```
relations = db.session.query(Entity).join(Relation.entity_id1)\     .join(Relation.entity_id2).distinct(Entity.name).filter((Relation.entity_id1 == PARAMETER)
                                                                | (Relation.entity_id2 == PARAMTER)
                                                                & (Entity.entity_id != PARAMETER))
```

Any advice or debugging help would be appreciated!

Edit: more info about the use case: "Entities" are nodes of an undirected graph and "Relations" are edges. (Relation.entity_id1 | Relation.entity_id2 is the same as Relation.entity_id2 | Relation.entity_id1) All edge source and destinations are guaranteed to have a corresponding node. The goal is given an entity_id = PARAMETER, find all adjacent nodes to that entity.

Comment: While it is a similar question, this question involves joins which the linked question does not.

Comment: In your example attempt, you have a misspelling, `PARAMTER`.

Comment: Is that a right join on purpose? Seems just a bit odd that you want distinct attributes from the left relation, which will mean a row of NULLs may be included.

Comment: @Ilja that is a great point. I'm trying to simulate a graph where "Entities" are nodes and "Relations" are edges. The reason for the distinct is the graph is undirected so "fk_A fk_B" is the same as "fk_B fk_A". Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @SuperShoot great eye! In this case "PARAMETER" (or PARAMTR....)  is just a place holder I included for simplicity.